# Clarification on final step of proof of binomial theorem by induction.

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I had a question with regards to the final step in proving the binomial theorem using induction. After changing indices on the second term I arrive at the following:

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^{j} + \sum_{j = 1}^{k + 1}\binom{k}{j - 1}a^{k+1-j}b^{j}$$

It is the following step that I'm having an issue with. I know that $\binom{k+1}{j} = \binom{k}{j} + \binom{k}{j-1}$.

I'm having trouble justifying to myself the next steps. Now what I would like to do is group everything together under one summation and then factor out the shared terms:

$$ \sum_{j = 0}^{k+1}\bigg[\binom{k}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^{j} + \binom{k}{j - 1}a^{k+1-j}b^{j}\bigg] = \sum_{j = 0}^{k+1}\bigg(\binom{k}{j} + \binom{k}{j-1}\bigg)a^{k+1-j}b^{j}$$

This would then result in the desired final result:

$$ \sum_{j = 0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}a^{k+1-j}b^{j}$$

My issue is with the indices. As can be seen when $j = 0$ I will end up with a negative value in my second binomial coefficient, not a good thing. So what or how do I reconcile that one piece to be able to have the factorization work out the way I envision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is define $\binom{k}{j} = 0$ if $j < 0$ or $j>k$.  That way $\binom{k+1}{j} = \binom{k}{j} + \binom{k}{j-1}$ is still true when $j=0$.

Otherwise, you have to restrict the statement of Pascal's identity:
$$
    \binom{k+1}{j} = 
    \begin{cases}
        1 & j=0 \\
        1 & j=k+1 \\
        \binom{k}{j} + \binom{k}{j-1} & 1 \leq j \leq k
    \end{cases}
$$

Comment: I was wondering if I am "allowed" to do this, that was my initial thinking as well...

Comment: @dc3rd see my edit.  Not only is it allowed, it's pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.